# Realtime validation in database with custom field validator

Tags: asp.net, forms

I am creating a registration form in asp.net and I am trying to figure out how to check if the requested username is available upon lostfocus of the text field.

I setup a custom validation field but I can't seem to make it work on lostfocus.

Is there a way to do it?
What should I read?

Thanks

Comment: did my answer help frnd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you can check the username exist or not in custom validator. just check the url below. IT checks the user is exist or not.

Attach a custom validator to your textbox that hooks up to a validation method server side.
Using javascript, you'll need to hook up an eventhandler to the focusout event and make an ajax call. That call will send the value back to the server and get a response of valid or not.
http://brian.dobberteen.com/code/jquery_ajax_custom_validator/

Comment: It was the js that I was missing! :)